# I have an indentation error in python 3 in an elif statement how do I fix this

Tags: python

I keep getting an indentation error on line 17 but I cannot figure out why, this is a code from a tutorial I found online (`https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/porcupine-python/`)

this is the error message:

```
File "/home/luke/Documents/wake_word/wake_word.py", line 17
    elif keyword_index == 1:
    ^
Indentation Error: expected an indented block
```

I am using vim text editor and python3, here's my code:

```
import pvporcupine

porcupine = pvporcupine.create(
  access_key='${ACCESS_KEY}',
  keywords=['picovoice', 'bumblebee']
)

def get_next_audio_frame():
  pass


while True:
  audio_frame = get_next_audio_frame()
  keyword_index = porcupine.process(audio_frame)
  if keyword_index == 0:
      # detected `porcupine`
  elif keyword_index == 1:
      # detected `bumblebee`
```

Comment: comments do not count as (indeted) code... insert [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) along with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Comments do not count as a statement. To add a null statement, put `pass` keyword below the `if`/`elif`/`else` condition to avoid errors.
Also, an `else` statement after would help eliminate any future problems.

Eg:

```
if keyword_index == 0:
      pass
      # detected `porcupine`
  elif keyword_index == 1:
      pass
      # detected `bumblebee`
```

Comment: Why? There would still be nothing after the `if keyword_index == 0:` to execute (there won't be an indented block) and there will still be the error (I think).

Comment: Because the python interpreter ignores comments (the point of a comment), and blank ifs will raise a syntax error.

Comment: I agree with David.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not taken in account by the interpreter. So it sees:

```py
if keyword_index == 0:
elif keyboard_index == 1:
```

and this is an illegal code because there's no things to execute after the `:`.

I suggest adding the keyword `pass` after the `:` llike this:

```py
if keyword_index == 0:
   # detected `porcupine`
   pass
elif keyboard_index == 1:
   # detected `bumblebee`
   pass
```

so the interpreter will know there's nothing to do and will not say, "I see nothing to execute so let's raise an error".

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: If you no longer need answers, you can mark an answer as accepted so that everyone will see that the problem is solved.